# Buscar por destinatario en archivo binario con char C++

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de hacer una busqueda secuencial con char en un archivo binario, para buscar por destinatario en una clase llamada Correo.
Tengo que utilizar la funcion seekp y despues read para posicionarme en el registro pero no logro hacerlo bien.

Hice una funcion de buscar por la posicion segun esta sea char pero no se si este bien implementada o pueda funcionar, ya trate de hacer la busqueda directa en el archivo pero no me imprime nada puesto que no encuentra el registro destinatario dentro del archivo

Alguna buena persona que me oriente?

```
void Archivo::buscarRemitente(char& f)
{
    Correo c;
    char remi[20];
    char *aux;

    archivo.open("emails.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (archivo.fail()){
        cout << "Ocurrio un error al abrir el archivo" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        //archivo.close();
        // cout << "Introduce el remitente a buscar: " << endl;
        // cin >> remi;

        //posición = NRR * (cantidad de bytes por registro) 
        int posicion ;
        //posicion = c.getId() * ()

        archivo.seekp(apuntadorCadena(f));
        // archivo.seekg(0);
        archivo.read((char* )&c, sizeof(Correo));
        archivo.close();
        //cin.getline(remi,20);
        cout << c.getRemitente() << endl;
    //if (remi == c.getRemitente()){

            cout << "Correo encontrado!" << endl;
            cout << "ID: " << c.getId() << endl;
            cout << "Remitente: " << c.getRemitente() << endl;
            cout << "Destinatario: " << c.getDestinatario() << endl;
            cout << "Copia carbono: " << c.getCopiaCarbono() << endl;
            cout << "Copia carbono ciega: " << c.getCopiaCarbonoCiega() << endl;
            cout << "Asunto: " << c.getAsunto() << endl;
            cout << "Contenido: " << c.getContenido() << endl;
        // }
        // else {
        //     cout << "No se pudo encontrar en correo" << endl;
        // }

        
    }
}

char Archivo::apuntadorCadena(char& c){
    return (c-1) * sizeof(Correo);
}
```

Llamadas a la funcion del menu:

```
void Menu::menuOpciones()
{
    char *puntero;
    char temp[200];
    puntero = temp;
    unsigned long int posicion;
    unsigned long int buscar;
    char dest;

    switch(opcion){
        case 1:
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "Datos del nuevo correo" << endl;
                cout << "ID: " << endl;
                cin >> posicion;
                correo.setId(posicion);
                cin.ignore();

                cout << "Remitente: " << endl;
                cin.getline(temp,20);
                correo.setRemitente(puntero);

                cout << "Destinatario: " << endl;
                cin.getline(temp,50);
                correo.setDestinatario(puntero);

                cout << "Copia carbono: " << endl;
                cin.getline(temp,50);
                correo.setCopiaCarbono(puntero);

                cout << "Copia carbono ciega: " << endl;
                cin.getline(temp,20);
                correo.setCopiaCarbonoCiega(puntero);

                cout << "Asunto: " << endl;
                cin.getline(temp,50);
                correo.setAsunto(puntero);

                cout << "Contenido: " << endl;
                cout << "Para enviar escribe -EXIT-" << endl;
                correo.setContenido();
                cout << endl << endl;

                archivo.escribir(correo, posicion);

                break;
            }
        case 2:
            {
                cout << "Ingresa el ID del correo a buscar: " << endl;
                cin >> posicion;
                archivo.leer(posicion);
                break;
            }
        case 3:
            {
                cout << "Ingresa el ID del correo a modificar: " << endl;
                cin >> posicion;
                archivo.modificar(posicion);
                break;
                
            }
        case 4:
            {
                cout << "Introduce el remitente a buscar: " << endl;
                cin >> dest;

                //cin.getline(temp,20);
                // char* p = temp;
                // p=temp;

                //cin.getline(puntero,20);
                archivo.buscarRemitente(dest);
                break;
            }
        case 5:
            {
                break;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nadie salvo tu conoce el formato del archivo "emails.dat", luego tampoco será posible arreglar el código. No queda para nada claro cómo se podría determinar la posición de un registro en el archivo a partir de un único caracter... entiendo que ahí deberías recibir el nombre del destinatario o algo que identificase el registro, pero claro, sin saber qué hay en el archivo es complicado. ¿Qué es `Correo`? Supongo que una clase o una estructura, pero es imposible saberlo y, de serlo, tampoco conocemos sus miembros ni nada. Faltan muchos datos

Comment: Hola, perdon. Trate de simplificar lo mas el codigo para que no fuera abrumador. Aqui esta el codigo completo: https://github.com/alan-martinez/Proyect_email

Comment: Esto no funciona así. Todo lo que haga falta debe estar en la pregunta, la idea es que las respuestas puedan servir a más gente, no solamente a ti. Si, por ejemplo, el repositorio deja de existir en el futuro, la respuesta entonces no será de utilidad para nadie. Te toca sintetizar y resumirlo todo lo suficiente como para que quede una pregunta completa sin ser demasiado extensa

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.